# ValueError Traceback (most recent call last), python scrapy terminal

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, scrapy

i run this code on in terminal scrapy shell, it produce an error as ValueError Traceback. too many values to unpack (expected 2). 
eg : brand - A , cat - AA,BB,CC,DD
     brand - B , cat - AA,SS,DD,FF

```
    scrapy shell 
    cats = response.xpath('//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodePopup"]')
    brands = response.xpath('//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNode"]')
    for cat, brand in cats, brands:
        ca = cat.xpath('.//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodePopupColumn"]/a/@href').extract()
        br = brand.xpath('.//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodeName"]/text()').extract()
        print(ca)
        print(br)
```

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure , cats + brands are same in length ? if yes then use as:

```
for cat, brand in zip(cats, brands):
    #Your work goes here.
```

Comment: No, they are not the same length. brand is always single ones, but the cat are having multiple items. like brand-A ,cat-AA,BB,CC..

Comment: Then you can't loop them together., What you actually want ?
you might need to have nested loop to achieve your result.

Comment: i want something like this, but its not producing an output. the length of both brands and cats are same-- cats = response.xpath('//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodePopup"]')
        brands = response.xpath('//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNode"]')
        for cat,brand in cats, brands:
            ca = cat.xpath('.//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodePopupColumn"]/a/@href').extract()
            br = brand.xpath('.//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodeName"]/text()').extract()
            for c in ca:
                yield{'br':br, 'c':c}

Comment: can you provide us the link from where you are scraping, so that we can better understand the data complexity and your need.

Comment: The answer "for cat, brand in zip(cats, brands):" worked well. Thankyou

Comment: That's great :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    cats = response.xpath('//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodePopup"]')
    brands = response.xpath('//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNode"]')
    for cat,brand in zip(cats, brands):
        ca = cat.xpath('.//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodePopupColumn"]/a')
        br = brand.xpath('.//*[@class="leftNavCategoriesNodeName"]/text()').extract()
        for c in ca:
            cq = c.xpath('.//@href').extract()
            yield{'br':br, 'cq':cq}
```